# Fullcalendar add image to only 1 column of the resource

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Fullcalendar is great, and I can add an image to the resourceObject using the resourceRender callback.
I am using a calendar based on the resource grouping demo.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/resourceColumns-grouping-demo

But the problem is I only want to add the image to the 3rd column - Occupancy, but not the first 2.

When I add the following code, it appends the image to all columns, not just the occupancy column.

```
resourceRender: function(resourceObj, labelTds, bodyTds) {
   labelTds.append(
     '<div style="text-align:center">' + 
     '<img src="../../images/icon.png" width="30" height="30">' +                    
     '</div>'
    };
},
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this to only the Occupancy td element?

Comment: if you know the ID of the third resource, you could do something like:
`//if the id happens to be 3
if(resourceObj.id==3){
//do code to append the image here 
}
` 
This only works if your resource never change. If you have changing resources for each day you could maybe add a custom field to your resource called type. 
then do something like that:

`if(resourceObj.type == 'needsImage'){
//append image here
}
`

Comment: Hi,
I tried this it does not work. The first argument to the resourceRender function resourceObj,  is the same for all the items of the resource.
When you look at the labelTds object, there is an array [] of  3 td elements.
When you use the calll to 
labelTds.append(...)
It appends the html to all 3 elements.
I tried to edit the array offset directly,  but it did nothing.

I think I am looking for the way to append the html to a specific indexed value of labelTds,  but I don't know the function call to do it.

Comment: Hmm looks like the V4 version renders differently. Check out this here 
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/release-notes#resource-rendering

Comment: Thanks, it isn't in the documentation, the documentation only got me to adding the extra html via append. However, there is not documentation on modification of a single element, and I cannot seem to find any documentation of the labelTds object functions.

Comment: Found it.  Just use the jQuery functions to iterate through the list, then call append.
It this case the Occupancy <td> was the last element.

labelTds.last().empty();  //  Clear the element
labelTds.last().append(  // Append my image html.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
First, as suggested by John, add additional resources to the resourceObj, so you can select which lines to add the images too.
Then use jQuery list functions to iterate through the labelTds array to add the image in the desired td element in the array of labelTds.
In this example the last row - Occupancy was the td element to replace with an image.
Also, you can add in 'onclick' javascript to your image to perform additional actions.

Example code below.

```
resourceRender: function(resourceObj, labelTds, bodyTds) {
    if(resourceObj.roomtype != 'Manage' ) {
        var roomid = resourceObj.id;
        var roomno = resourceObj.roomno;
        var msg = 'Peform some action on '+roomno+' ?';
        if(resourceObj.roomstatus == 'C') {
            labelTds.last().empty();
            labelTds.last().append(
                '<div style="text-align:center">' +
                '<img src="../../images/image1.png" width="20" height="20" onclick="confirm(\''+msg+'\');">' +
                '</div>'
            );
        };
        if(resourceObj.roomstatus == 'L') {
            labelTds.last().empty();
            labelTds.last().append(
                '<div style="text-align:center">' +
                '<img src="../../images/image2.png" width="20" height="20">' +
                '</div>'
            );
        };
    };
},
```